# Rancher deleting the ipsec service

Tags: rancher

It's been causing me only issues so far and all the containers I run are started with `--net=host` anyway. I was wondering if I could delete this service without any issue. Rancher forums are not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue on https://github.com/rancher/rancher with logs from the following containers: network-manager, rancher-metadata, ipsec-router, ipsec-cni*.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Probably, if you are not using Cattle as a scheduler or health checks.

The longer answer: No, IPsec is a requirement of both the health check service and the Cattle scheduler.

You can actually test this in the navigating to "Manage Environments" under the environments dropdown and creating a new environment template. Disable IPsec service and then launch a new environment using that template. The health check and scheduler services will fail to start since they require the managed network.